# LocalStorage removes the wrong value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I keep having the same issue again and again : When I add a task, it gets added to the localStorage correctly. But once I have multiple tasks and I click complete on a random one, sometimes it happens that the LocalStorage removes the task before it or after it. I can't figure out a way how to let it work.

```js
let addBtn = document.getElementById("addButton");
let textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
let mainList =  document.getElementById("mainList");
let storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("toDos")) || [];

if (storage.length != 0){
  for (let i=0; i<storage.length;i++){
    addTask(mainList, storage[i]);
  };
};

function addTask(list,task){
 var newTask = document.createElement("li");
 newTask.textContent=task
  newTask.className="task d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item bg-primary mt-2";
  addCompleteBtn(newTask);
  list.appendChild(newTask);
}

function addCompleteBtn (newTask){
  let completeBtn = document.createElement("button");
  completeBtn.className="btn btn-success completeBtn";
  completeBtn.textContent="Completed";
  newTask.appendChild(completeBtn);
};

  addBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  if(textInput.value === ""){
    alert("Error: The field is either empty or you entered more than 100 characters!");
  }else{
    storage.push(textInput.value);      
    addTask(mainList, textInput.value);
    textInput.value="";
    localStorage.setItem("toDos",JSON.stringify(storage));
  };
});
    
mainList.addEventListener("click",(evt)=>{
    if (evt.target.className==="btn btn-success completeBtn") {
       let listItem = evt.target.parentNode;
       let mainUl = listItem.parentNode;
       let toBeRemoved = listItem.textContent;
       storage.splice(storage.indexOf(toBeRemoved),1);
       mainUl.removeChild(listItem);
       localStorage.setItem("toDos",JSON.stringify(storage));
 };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>To-do-list App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="jumbotron bg-info">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Task List</h1>
    <p class="lead text-center">Click on the Add button to add a task</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstInput input-group mb-5">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addButton">Add Task</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" title='Enter a Task' class="form-control" id="textInput" maxlength="200">
    </div>
  </div>
      <ul class='tasksList container' id="mainList">
      </ul>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Shows all the values in the LocalStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8V8T.png)

[Once task 2 is removed, task 3 is removed from the Storage instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEc20.png)

this is the specific part that causes me issues :

```js
mainList.addEventListener("click",(evt)=>{
    if (evt.target.className==="btn btn-success completeBtn") {
       let listItem = evt.target.parentNode;
       let mainUl = listItem.parentNode;
       let toBeRemoved = listItem.textContent;
       /* This is the part of code causing me issues
       storage.splice(storage.indexOf(toBeRemoved),1);
       */
       mainUl.removeChild(listItem);
       localStorage.setItem("toDos",JSON.stringify(storage));
 };
});
```

Comment: please point to the specific part of code

Comment: I have edited the main post commenting out the part of code that causes the issue.

Comment: so if it's your `storage` contents that are incorrect, it actually has nothing to do with `localStorage`, right?

Comment: try doing some debugging. hit `console.log(toBeRemoved)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here `let toBeRemoved = listItem.textContent;`,this will return the text content of all elements inside that `li`. So if you add a task named 'Task 1', when you press Completed the value of `toBeRemoved` will be `Task 1Completed` since this will return the text of the button as well since your button is a child of the `li`.

So change `let toBeRemoved = listItem.textContent;` to `let toBeRemoved = listItem.childNodes[0].nodeValue;` and you should be fine, this will get the text of the li only.

Comment: @iDome89 great:)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it helped me so much to understand also the whole process.

Comment: More specifically, because your `indexOf` was returning -1, you were always removing the _last_ element of the array.    As I suggested above, this was never about `localStorage` and the question title is misleading.